# How to decompress bitmap in VB.Net Server that was compressed by Java Client

Tags: java, android, vb.net, tcpclient, tcpserver

I'm trying to have android send an image to vb.net server via tcp/ip. Android compresses the bitmap and when the server receives the bitmap and converts it to image it comes to all black I think that decompression might be the issue or something else. I don't really know how to decompress that image. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

This is the Java to create the bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

This is my vb.net server

```
Sub Main()
    Dim bmp As Bitmap

    Dim serverSocket As New TcpListener(1334)
    Dim requestCount As Integer
    Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
    serverSocket.Start()

    While (True)
        Try
            msg("Waiting For Client...")
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()
            msg("Accept connection from client")
            requestCount = requestCount + 1
            Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
            Dim bytesFrom(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))

            Dim newImage As Image = Nothing
            Byte2Image(newImage, bytesFrom)
            newImage.Save("C:\Users\ppetrenko\Desktop\test.jpeg")


            Dim dataFromClient As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
            msg("Data from client -  " + dataFromClient)
            Dim serverResponse As String = "Server response " + Convert.ToString(requestCount)
            Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse)
            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
            networkStream.Flush()
            msg(serverResponse)
            clientSocket.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End While
```